# Can I load multiple files with one require statement?

Tags: node.js

maybe this question is a little silly, but is it possible to load multiple .js files with one require statement? like this:

```
var mylib = require('./lib/mylibfiles');
```

and use:

```
mylib.foo(); //return "hello from one"

mylib.bar(): //return "hello from two"
```

And in the folder mylibfiles will have two files:

**One.js**

```
exports.foo= function(){return "hello from one";}
```

**Two.js**

```
exports.bar= function(){return "hello from two";}
```

I was thinking to put a package.json in the folder that say to load all the files, but I don't know how. Other aproach that I was thinking is to have a index.js that exports everything again but I will be duplicating work.

Thanks!!

P.D: I'm working with nodejs v0.611 on a windows 7 machine

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First of all using `require` does not duplicate anything. It loads the module and it **caches** it, so calling `require` again will get it from memory (thus you can modify module at fly without interacting with its source code - this is sometimes desirable, for example when you want to store db connection inside module).

Also `package.json` does not load anything and does not interact with your app at all. It is only used for `npm`.

Now you cannot require multiple modules at once. For example what will happen if both `One.js` and `Two.js` have defined function with the same name?? There are more problems.

But what you can do, is to write additional file, say `modules.js` with the following content

```
module.exports = {
   one : require('./one.js'),
   two : require('./two.js'),
   /* some other modules you want */
}
```

and then you can simply use

```
var modules = require('./modules.js');
modules.one.foo();
modules.two.bar();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the thing was that i'm trying to have some methods as internal and I don't want that those functions can be access by the module that is using, in your example, modules.js. I think that in your example I can also do `var one = require(./one.js);` and get the same functions of `one.js`, is that so?

Comment: Correction: Node.js actually does read the `package.json` file's `main` field as part of the `require` process. That's the only thing Node reads from it, the rest of the info is for `npm`.

Answer (score 4):

I have a snippet of code that requires more than one module, but it doesn't clump them together as your post suggests. However, that can be overcome with a trick that I found.

```
function requireMany () {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).map(function (value) {
        try {
            return require(value)
        }
        catch (event) {
            return console.log(event)
        }
    })
}
```

And you use it as such

```
requireMany("fs", "socket.io", "path")
```

Which will return

```
[ fs {}, socketio {}, path {} ]
```

If a module is not found, an error will be sent to the console. It won't break the programme. The error will be shown in the array as undefined. The array will not be shorter because one of the modules failed to load.

Then you can bind those each of those array elements to a variable name, like so:

```
var [fs, socketio, path] = requireMany("fs", "socket.io", "path")
```

It essentially works like an object, but assigns the keys and their values to the global namespace. So, in your case, you could do:

```
var [foo, bar] = requireMany("./foo.js", "./bar.js")
foo() //return "hello from one"
bar() //return "hello from two"
```

---

And if you do want it to break the programme on error, just use this modified version, which is smaller

```
function requireMany () {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).map(require)
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't require() just work like this by default?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may require a **folder** as a module, according to the [node docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules). Let's say you want to require() a folder called `./mypack/`.

Inside `./mypack/`, create a `package.json` file with the `name` of the folder and a `main` javascript file with the same name, inside a `./lib/` directory.

```
{
  "name" : "mypack",
  "main" : "./lib/mypack.js"
}
```

Now you can use `require('./mypack')` and node will load `./mypack/lib/mypack.js`.

However if you do not include this `package.json` file, it may still work. Without the file, node will attempt to load `./mypack/index.js`, or if that's not there, `./mypack/index.node`.

My understanding is that this could be beneficial if you have split your program into many javascript files but do not want to concatenate them for deployment.

Comment: just to be clear though, you cannot require a folder as a module and have that load all the javascript files in that directory. right?

Comment: @Michael correct. it will only load the value of `main` in the root `package.json`, or if there is none, the root `index.js`

Comment: @Michael  - Dynamically loading a whole directory of code files has the same issue in virtually every language: What order should they be loaded in? Alphabetical? Then you get into weird contortions where you're putting artificial prefixes on filenames to influence the order.

Comment: @xyz ideally the order wouldn't matter - in my case this is true, each file just adds on functionality but doesn't actually execute any of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to map an array of exported modules from [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) statements in one line:

```
const requires = (...modules) => modules.map(module => require(module));
const [fs, path] = requires('fs', 'path');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar to what @freakish suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10554457/2668568) with a project where I've a list of test scripts that are pulled into a Puppeteer + Jest testing setup. My test files follow the naming convention testname1.js - testnameN.js and I was able use a generator function to require N number of files from the particular directory with the approach below:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = class FilesInDirectory {

    constructor(directory) {

        this.fid = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(directory));
        this.requiredFiles = (this.fid.map((fileId) => {
            let resolvedPath = path.resolve(directory, fileId);
            return require(resolvedPath);
        })).filter(file => !!file);

    }

    printRetrievedFiles() {
        console.log(this.requiredFiles);
    }

    nextFileGenerator() {

        const parent = this;
        const fidLength = parent.requiredFiles.length;

        function* iterate(index) {
            while (index < fidLength) {
                yield parent.requiredFiles[index++];
            }
        }
        return iterate(0);
    }

}
```

Then use like so:

```
//Use in test
const FilesInDirectory = require('./utilities/getfilesindirectory');
const StepsCollection = new FilesInDirectory('./test-steps');
const StepsGenerator = StepsCollection.nextFileGenerator();

//Assuming we're in an async function
await StepsGenerator.next().value.FUNCTION_REQUIRED_FROM_FILE(someArg);
```