# Bundling a bunch of require statements while avoiding namespacing

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've got a test suite and in each test file I find myself commonly importing a bunch of modules

```
const chai = require('chai')
const sinon = require('sinon')
const expect = chai.expect
const should = chai.should()
const testData = require('../test/test-data')
```

Is there any way to bundle all those `require` calls in one `require`, *without* using a namespace?

E.g something like this:

```
require('../test/test-bundle')

console.log(chai) // ok
console.log(sinon) // ok
console.log(expect) // ok
console.log(should) // ok
console.log(testData) // ok
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554241/can-i-load-multiple-files-with-one-require-statement

Comment: I'm asking for advice on how to do this *without* using a namespace, which the 'dupe' question doesn't ask - which I doubt is possible, but I'm asking anyway

Comment: I don't think it's possible without a namespace. At max, what you can do is put all the `require` statements within one file, and export the variables from that file. From your other file, you wold have to import only one file to get the necessary functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not say that my solution is very good, but it will allow you to reduce the number of duplicate code.
You could define a new module (test-util.js) and require all needed modules there. After that, in each test, require only one module and use destructuring assignment syntax to avoid namespace.

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

test-util.js:

```
module.exports = {
  chai: require('chai'),
  sinon: require('sinon'),
  expect: require('chai').expect,
  should: require('chai').should(),
  testData: require('../test/test-data')
};
```

test.js

```
let { chai, sinon, expect, should, testData } = require('./test-util.js');
```

Comment: Thanks - Small question - why `let` instead of `const`?

Comment: I prefer to use `const` only when it's really necessary. For defining string, number, etc. constants, for example: `const MAX_POWER = 10`. These const names are in upper case according node.js notation. For other cases I use `let`.