# Import multiple files in folder in React / Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm trying to import multiple files with a certain extension in a folder:

```
const allEntries = require.context('../static/blog', true, '/\.md/')
```

but I'm getting:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
```

I'm using [Nextjs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) and require the files in one of the pages. Something seems off here?

*Edit:* I don't necessarily need to do it via `require` I just want to be able to import/require multiple files at once without knowing the filename or how many of the files are in a folder.

Comment: I got this when I searched about your question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10554457/2405689

Comment: This would mean I need to know how many files are in a folder and require them each. I want to have a require or import which is by file extension and then I can loop over them to render.

Answer (score 1):

Try using require context npm library.

`$ npm i --save require-context`

In your file:

```
// Load globally into all modules.
require('require-context/register')

// Load locally as a function.
var requireContext = require('require-context');


function requireAll(r) { r.keys().forEach(r); } 

requireAll(requireContext('../static/blog', true, /\.md$/));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the following a try in webpack:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const allEntries = glob.sync("../static/blog/*.md");
```

The [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) will return an array of files. The array will contain all files with `.md` extension in the `../static/blog/` folder. Eventough there is a package it shouldn't be required to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are very close, from the error you are using webpack's [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext)

```js
const allEntries = require.context('../static/blog', true, '/\.md/')
console.log(allEntries.keys()) // all the files found in the context
allEntries.keys().forEach(allEntries) // require them all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const imageDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), '/public/dirname');
const imageFilenames = await fs.readdir(imageDirectory)
// Store the file names in an array and use it.
```

---

webpack.require is basically using webpack, make sure what you're using is webpack in fact